# Display all index positions available in an array in another variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, amcharts4

I want to access all indexes from an array to show each one of them in a different variable to generate an AmChart graph

```
let fieldsArrays = [[{ timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:44:47", fieldsArrays: 1 }],
    [{ timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:45:18", fieldsArrays: 200 }],
    [{ timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:47:19", fieldsArrays: 2500 }],
    ];
```

I tried a for loop but I'm not sure if it's the proper way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fieldsArrays.length; i++) {
    var innerArrayLength = fieldsArrays[i].length;
    for (var j = 0; j < innerArrayLength; j++) {
        console.log(fieldsArrays[i][j]);
    }
}

// This displays only one line in the graph. Each index should have it's own line in the AmChart graph
chart.data = fieldsArrays[0];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). What do you mean by *"to show each one of them in a different variable"*?

Comment: That's what you said above, but unfortunately, it doesn't make much sense. (Partially because you don't "show" things "in variables." Do you mean "store"/"put"? Each in its own individual variable?) What would the end result be? Is the number of entries in `fieldsArrays` always three, or does it vary?

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: do you want to flatten the array? what do you mean all positions? indexes will be `0-array length-1`

Comment: Can you add the expected result of the example you've provided ? i.e `[0, 1, 2, ...]`

Comment: @Alex so you need [1, 200, 2500] as output?

Comment: you can't explain because you don't understand what you really want, we cannot help until you paste actual output you want out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already noticed that you can't simply assign your fieldArrays variable directly to `chart.data` and get multiple lines appearing from it.  AmCharts only supports a flattened array of objects, not an array of arrays (note that every single one of our basic demos is a flattened array). AmCharts can't infer multiple lines from an array of arrays so you need to create series objects for each line you intend to display from your data set and tell those series objects how to interpret the data in your flattened array.

There are two approaches you can take to display multiple lines from your data.

1) Using `chart.data`, you have to flatten/combine and remap your array of arrays such that the values from your sub arrays correspond to their own individual value field property properties for each series (line). Given:

```
[
  [{ timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:44:47", fieldsArrays: 1 }, { timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:45:18",  fieldArrays: 10 }],
  [{ timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:45:18", fieldsArrays: 200 }, { timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:47:19", fieldsArrays: 150 }],
  [{ timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:45:18", fieldsArrays: 2100 }, { timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:47:19", fieldsArrays: 2500 }]
];
```

This needs to become something like this:

```
chart.data = [
  {
    timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:44:47",
    fieldsArrays: 1
  },
  {
    timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:45:18",
    fieldArrays: 10,
    fieldsArrays2: 200,
    fieldsArrays3: 2100
  },
  {
    timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:47:19",
    fieldsArrays2: 150,
    fieldsArrays3: 2500
  }
];
```

Each series object will have valueY (or valueX) correspond to the `fieldArrays` property associated with it:

```
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  // ...
  series.dataFields.valueY = "fieldArrays";
  series.dataFields.dateX = "timeAxe";
  // ...
  var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  // ...
  series2.dataFields.valueY = "fieldArrays2";
  series2.dataFields.dateX = "timeAxe";
  // ...
  // repeat for each unique valuefield property
```

2) If you prefer to keep the array of arrays, then you can assign each array directly into each series' own `data` array and keep your the same value field across all of your series. For example:

```
fieldArrays.forEach(function(fieldArray, index) {

  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.name = "Series " + (index + 1);
  series.dataFields.valueY = "fieldArrays";
  series.dataFields.dateX = "timeAxe";
  series.data = fieldArray; //assign array[0] to its own line, array[1] to its own line, etc  

  var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
});
```

Basic demo below:

```js
var fieldArrays = [
 [
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-26",
   "fieldArrays": 13
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-27",
   "fieldArrays": 12
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-28",
   "fieldArrays": 14
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-29",
   "fieldArrays": 11
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-30",
   "fieldArrays": 10
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-31",
   "fieldArrays": 10
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-08-01",
   "fieldArrays": 12
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-08-02",
   "fieldArrays": 15
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-08-03",
   "fieldArrays": 12
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-08-04",
   "fieldArrays": 12
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-26",
   "fieldArrays": 29
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-27",
   "fieldArrays": 30
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-28",
   "fieldArrays": 25
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-29",
   "fieldArrays": 30
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-30",
   "fieldArrays": 30
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-31",
   "fieldArrays": 30
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-08-01",
   "fieldArrays": 25
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-08-02",
   "fieldArrays": 22
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-08-03",
   "fieldArrays": 23
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-08-04",
   "fieldArrays": 24
  }
 ],
 [
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-26",
   "fieldArrays": 31
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-27",
   "fieldArrays": 45
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-28",
   "fieldArrays": 35
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-29",
   "fieldArrays": 36
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-30",
   "fieldArrays": 43
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-07-31",
   "fieldArrays": 33
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-08-01",
   "fieldArrays": 32
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-08-02",
   "fieldArrays": 33
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-08-03",
   "fieldArrays": 33
  },
  {
   "timeAxe": "2019-08-04",
   "fieldArrays": 35
  }
 ]
]


// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);


// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;


var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

fieldArrays.forEach(function(fieldArray, index) {

  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.name = "Series " + (index + 1);
  series.dataFields.valueY = "fieldArrays";
  series.dataFields.dateX = "timeAxe";
  series.data = fieldArray;
  
  
  var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
});


// Legend
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and taking your time to explain properly what should I do. I will try your solution (2nd approach) soon and will let you know how it behaves. I can't apply the first solution with map because I have a very long list of arrays in fieldsArrays. I would never have thought about series.data and that's an awesome suggestion.

Comment: Not quite sure what would cause this error off the top of my head. If you're still having this problem, can you post a fiddle that reproduces this?

Comment: The error disappeared after some minor work. It was related, I guess, to the cursor behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
chart.data = fieldsArrays.flatMap(([{timeAxe, fieldsArrays}]) => ({ timeAxe: new Date(timeAxe), fieldsArrays }));
```

**Live example:**

```js
let fieldsArrays = [
  [{
    timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:44:47",
    fieldsArrays: 1
  }],
  [{
    timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:45:18",
    fieldsArrays: 200
  }],
  [{
    timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:47:19",
    fieldsArrays: 2500
  }],
];

const chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
const lineSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
lineSeries.dataFields.valueY = "fieldsArrays";
lineSeries.dataFields.dateX = "timeAxe";
lineSeries.name = "Fields Arrays";
lineSeries.tensionX = 0.8;
var circleBullet = lineSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
circleBullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
circleBullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
circleBullet.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";

// Legend
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

chart.data = fieldsArrays.flatMap(([{timeAxe, fieldsArrays}]) => ({ timeAxe: new Date(timeAxe), fieldsArrays }));
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: That's *really* speculating about what the OP is after... Still, you may be right. :-)

Comment: @Alex What about now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
let fieldsArrays = [[{ timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:44:47", fieldsArrays: 1 }],
  [{ timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:45:18", fieldsArrays: 200 }],
  [{ timeAxe: "2019-1-27 0:47:19", fieldsArrays: 2500 }],
];

let display_each_index_available_in_fieldsArrays = [];

for (var i = 0; i < fieldsArrays.length; i++) {
    var innerArrayLength = fieldsArrays[i].length;
    for (var j = 0; j < innerArrayLength; j++) {
        display_each_index_available_in_fieldsArrays.push(fieldsArrays[i][j]);
    }
}

console.log(display_each_index_available_in_fieldsArrays);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it but the behaviour is like .flat() This code is to be used in AmChart library to generate a graph. In this graph I need all those indexes separately if it's possible.